# Fragment shader smooth opacity

Tags: opengl, shader, fragment-shader

What I want to achieve is quite simple, given

```
a center point
a radius
a color
```

draw a circle at center point with given color filled in.

The center of the circle with 100% color and the color fade out the way along the radius.

Here is what I have achieved

(bgColor: 10, 20, 30, 255, lightColor: 100, 100, 30, 255):

[image]

The shader code for fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec2 center;
uniform vec4 lightColor;
uniform float lightRadius;

void main()
{
    float distance = abs(distance(center, gl_FragCoord.xy));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor * (1.0 - 1.0 / lightRadius * distance));
}
```

The problem is that the color fading from center to edge is not SMOOTH (it might too seem to be that obvious in the screenshot above though).

I wonder if there is any way to make it a smooth fade out circle?

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: [Just to be clear, are you referring to these "ripples" as it not being smooth?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x63La.png)

Comment: ...[`mix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml)?

Comment: Yes I mean those ripples ...

Comment: This phenomenon is called "banding".  If banding bothers you, one way to fix it is to implement some kind of "dithering" technique in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:if I wanna do smth like that i'll just use tweaked phong lighting . Vector math is better for gradients I think. 
Currently you can try change `1.o` to `1.0LF`. It's `#version 400 core` stuff